# Entity Framework 4.1: many-to-many with the same object in collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have a model with many-to-many relation.

I also have `object1` and `object2` entities. Object1 has a `ICollection<Object2>` property. Object2 has a `ICollection<Object1>`.

The problem is that Object1 may have more than one Object2 with the same key (Id). I mean that it is possible situation that `ICollection<Object2>` may have `{Id=1, Id=2, Id=1, Id=3... etc}` objects.
Then I'm calling SaveChanges only `{Id=1, Id=2, Id=3}` are saved in Database. How can I save many same objects of Object1 instance in many-to-many relation?

Comment: How do you have the same ID for more than one objects of the same entity? The keys should be unique per object.

Comment: Why not?  For example, I want to have more than one copy of objects in my property collection. (For example, imagine menu order. You have menu items and you have orders. You may order two stakes (menu item 'stake') to one order)

Comment: Yea, that makes sense. But i think you should still have another ID to distinguish between the two 'stakes'. So you'd have two ID's. One unique (ItemId), and one not unique (ItemTypeID). It will make it easier for you to track and save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will need to do this with two one-to-many collections and an association object in the middle, e.g. `Object1Object2Assoc`. This object would also need a `Count` property to represent its order in the collection and/or an Id property to distinguish itself from other similar associations.

Comment: got your idea. I think this is a solution.